# openrewrite: The type de.danielbechler.diff.ObjectDiffer cannot be resolved

Tags: openrewrite

When writing a Java recipe for openrewrite using maven, the class ObjectDiffer cannot be resolved:
The type de.danielbechler.diff.ObjectDiffer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.openrewrite.TreeVisitor

I was following the environment setup guide https://docs.openrewrite.org/authoring-recipes/recipe-development-environment using maven.

Any hint which dependency is missing for this type?

Comment: Having only briefly looked into this I think we manage that dependency here:
https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/c54853fde749c90474d343b7cc0eb914d2d4fa4f/rewrite-core/build.gradle.kts#L11